# Android Espresso - Wait until dialog is displayed

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

What are the possible ways to write tests to wait for a dialog, should support both dialogFragment and Dialog(AlertDialog) ?.

Comment: You should not need to write any code that waits on dialogs. Espresso will wait for you. If you're having an issue with this, you should ask a question specifically around that.

Comment: @dominicoder espresso(dialog) by default does wait only for 10 seconds, but if your app shows some dialog based on API calls that may take more that 10 seconds then for that you have to have your own custom assertion.

Comment: I would argue that that in a test environment you should be mocking out API calls and never find yourself in a case where a UI test showing a dialog blocks for more than 10 seconds. In any case, it sounds like you want a custom IdlingResource to tell Espresso that your app is busy while showing the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I was able to figure out, posting sample code may help others. The idea is keep periodically checking until real timeout happens.

```
public static void waitForDialogWithText(String text, long timeout) {
    waitForDialog(withText(text), timeout);
}

private static void waitForDialog(Matcher<View> viewMatcher, long timeout) {
    final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
    Exception exception = null;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
        try {
            // wait for x second // Thread.sleep(x mills)
            onView(viewMatcher).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exception = e;
        }
    }
    if (exception != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```